# How do I execute db.SaveChanges() then update database again?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, post, controller

In my controller during `POST`, how do I update my `USERS` entity and then use that newly created `UserID` to assign a role to them in my `USERROLES` table. Below is the code I have currently, it errors when attempting to save the second set of changes.

My `USERROLES` table consists of a combination of their `UserID` and a `RoleID`. The `UserID` in `USERS` is auto-generated when inserted into the table.

If someone could inform me of how to actually work around this that would be fantastic - I'm still pretty new to ASP MVC.

```
using (var db = new SwinTCSEntities()) // initialise db object
{
    // add values to USERS
    db.USERS.Add(new USERS
    {
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        Username = model.Username,
        Password = Crypto.HashPassword("pass1234"),
        Email = model.Email,
        OfficeNo = model.OfficeNo,
        PhoneNo = model.PhoneNo,
        RegistrationDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        MeetingNotifications = true,
        SubmissionNotifications = true,
        TeamAssignNotifications = true,
        OverdueNotifications = true
    });
    db.SaveChanges(); // this goes through fine

    if (db.USERS.Any(x => x.Username == model.Username)) // it's able to get the new user value
    {
        if (model.IsAdmin && !model.IsStudent)
        {
            db.USERROLES.Add(new USERROLES
            {
                UserID = db.USERS.First(x => x.Username == model.Username).UserID,
                RoleID = db.ROLES.First(x => x.Name == "Admin").RoleID,
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now
            });
            // It errors here with a concurrency error
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var db = new SwinTCSEntities()) // initialise db object
{
    // create USERS object
    var user = new USERS
    {
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        Username = model.Username,
        Password = Crypto.HashPassword("pass1234"),
        Email = model.Email,
        OfficeNo = model.OfficeNo,
        PhoneNo = model.PhoneNo,
        RegistrationDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        MeetingNotifications = true,
        SubmissionNotifications = true,
        TeamAssignNotifications = true,
        OverdueNotifications = true
    };


   //load the admin role in the EF context and add it to this new user
        if (model.IsAdmin && !model.IsStudent)
        {
            var adminRole = db.ROLES.First(x => x.Name == "Admin");
            user.USERROLES.Add(new USERROLES
            {
                Role = adminRole,
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now
            });
        }


    //add the user to the USERS set  
    db.USERS.Add(user);

    db.SaveChanges(); // EF is smart enough to link the entities on SaveChanges

}
```

Comment: I still get a concurrency exception upon reaching db.SaveChanges() when modified to use a `users` object. Any ideas?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SaveChanges 2 times, I can  you show anothers solution:
1. I thins so  your new user has unique ID yes? so use try and catch methods or somthing like this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = userViewModel.Email, Email = userViewModel.Email };
            var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password);

            //Add User to the selected Roles 
            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (selectedRoles != null)
                {
                    var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRoles);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", adminresult.Errors.First());
                ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");
                return View();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

you can  change selected roles as you need method sorry for my english.